# page hanged when web method is executes

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, webmethod

I am working on an ajax-webmethod (using json) to save data in a database and select it when needed. Now whenever I call the webmethod, while the method is processed the whole page hangs and nothing can be done with the page.

I want to enable everything while the web method is called from ajax, for example showing a loading image until the web method finishes.

My code is below:

```
function getvalues(id, tab, pageNo) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "default.aspx/LoadData",
        data: "{'id':'" + id + "','tab':'" + tab + "','pageNo':'" + pageNo + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            if (msg.d.length > 0) {
                var dvComment = document.getElementById("Comments");
                dvComment.innerHTML += msg.d;
            }  
        },
        async: true,
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            // alert(xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

So now when it renders the html into the DIV the whole time the page hangs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show loading image you can use `ajaxStart` method like this:

```
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).show();
});
```

Where `#loading` is:

```
<img id="loading" src="images/ajaxload.gif" alt="loading..." style="display:none"/>
```

To hide loading image:

```
$("#loading").ajaxComplete(function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply and this solved my half issue
but I want the page to be click ableable  like I can scroll the page during the execution of the webmethod, or I should be able to select some text etc.

Comment: Also there is a java script timer function in my page which will call after every minute to update a content of a <span> which is using the same json-ajax call a web method. The issue is there as well as after every minute the update time method calls the page once again hanged out for some moment.
Please tell me a way to get rid from this ugly behavior of web method execution.

Comment: @tanweer it is not ugly behavoiur of web methods. You should disable the timer once you start ajax request and re-enable it in `success` and `error` delegates so that another request does not fires untill first one is completed. I think this is the most probable reason why your page is slowing down.